# C# - Interactive Brokers API - get market data

Tags: c#, data-structures, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to use the basis Interactive Broker API in C# to Forex market data. My goal is to get the bid and ask price of multiple currency pairs.

Here is what I have now. Main:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using IBApi;

namespace TWS_Data
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //IB's main object
            EWrapperImpl ibClient = new EWrapperImpl();

            //Connect
            ibClient.ClientSocket.eConnect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 0);

            //Creat and define a contract to fetch data for
            Contract contract = new Contract();
            contract.Symbol = "EUR";
            contract.SecType = "CASH";
            contract.Currency = "USD";
            contract.Exchange = "IDEALPRO";

            // Create a new TagValue List object (for API version 9.71) 
            List<TagValue> mktDataOptions = new List<TagValue>();


            // calling method every X seconds
            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            e => ibClient.ClientSocket.reqMktData(1, contract, "", true, mktDataOptions),
            null,
            TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

         }
    }
}
```

The API function "reqMktData" calls the following two functions:

```
        public virtual void tickSize(int tickerId, int field, int size)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tick Size. Ticker Id:" + tickerId + ", Field: " + field + ", Size: " + size + "\n");
        }

        public virtual void tickPrice(int tickerId, int field, double price, int canAutoExecute)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tick Price. Ticker Id:" + tickerId + ", Field:" + field + ", Price:" + price + ", CanAutoExecute: " + canAutoExecute + "\n");
            string str = Convert.ToString(price);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\price.txt", str);
        }
```

In this code I am trying to save the market data on my hard drive as a dummy test. However, here my problem comes up. During one run the function tickPrice(..) gets called 6 times and deliveres 6 different prices (see the API guide here: https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/apiguide/java/tickprice.htm)

**What I would need to know now is** how it is possible in C# to save these individual results somehow ? (they all get posted into the console, but obviously only the last price is the one that stayes saved in the file).

I am quiet familiar with Matlab coding, but new to the C# syntax. So I am somehow thinking in forms of vectors or for loops to solve this, but it doesn't work out that way.

Thanks for any help or hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use List to store all values, like:

```
    List<string> priceList = new List<string>();
    public virtual void tickPrice(int tickerId, int field, double price, int canAutoExecute)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tick Price. Ticker Id:" + tickerId + ", Field:" + field + ", Price:" + price + ", CanAutoExecute: " + canAutoExecute + "\n");

        // here you add your prices to list
        priceList.Add(price);

        string str = Convert.ToString(price);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\price.txt", str);
    }
```

For getting the last entry from list:

```
    string lastPrice = priceList[priceList.Count - 1];
```

Comment: I am using the same function/code, but the callback functions tickPrice or tickSize are not getting fired. May you please guide me a little bit, as i am dealing first time with IBAPI.

Comment: @AneeqAzamKhan Unfortunately I am not familiar with IBAPI, can't help you there :(

Answer (score 1):

I did this by storing the values from the callback as instance variables in a previously created List collection of objects.

I called the `reqMarketData()` function from inside a loop and I made the loop's iteration a static integer in the main program class, so it could be identified from `EWrapperImpl`'s callback functions, such as `tickPrice()`.

The loop goes through the length of your collection of objects (one object for each underlying contract in my case). This way, the following example code in the EWrapperImpl's callback will save the data for each request in an object from the collection.

```
public virtual void tickPrice(int tickerId, int field, double price, int canAutoExecute)      
{         
  Program.exampleCollection[Program.exampleIteration].ExamplePriceVar = price;
}
```

You can then access the data outside of the `EWrapperImpl` callback by using the collection. (the sample code doesn't show the creation of the collection instance, object instances, or instance variables)

Comment: I am using the same function/code, but the callback functions tickPrice or tickSize are not getting fired. May you please guide me a little bit, as i am dealing first time with IBAPI.

Answer (score 1):

To address the issue of your data being returned multiple times rather than just once:

-You need to identify which field you want to use the `price` for.  It's going to give you multiple fields no matter what.  In your case with `tickPrice()`, each field stands for a different type of price.

```
public virtual void tickPrice(int tickerId, int field, double price, int canAutoExecute)
    {
        if (field == 4)
        {
            //here, price is equal to the "last" price.
        }
        else
        {
        }

        if (field == 9)
        {
            //here, price is equal to the "close" price.
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using the same function/code, but the callback functions tickPrice or tickSize are not getting fired. May you please guide me a little bit, as i am dealing first time with IBAPI.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that `File.WriteAllText` overrides content of file if it exists. That's why you see only latest data.

But what you need is to append data to file, for example:

```
  using (var file = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\price.txt"))
       file.WriteLine(str);
```

However, I believe you subscribed to multiple instruments and recieve ticks from different threads. in this case at some time you will get exception, that file is busy, so you need something more sophisticated to log data(for example NLog).

Comment: I am using the same function/code, but the callback functions tickPrice or tickSize are not getting fired. May you please guide me a little bit, as i am dealing first time with IBAPI.